# Decomposition of graph to subgraphs according to parallel edges

Tags: graphs, shortest-path, adjacency-matrix

I am supposed to calculate all-pair shortest path lengths of a graph. However, I first need the graph to be decomposed/expanded to a **simple** one based on the presence of parallel edges.

If N parallel edges exist between any two vertices **A** and **B**, I need to create N replicas of both vertices. Each replica of **A** will be connected to **one and only one** replica of **B**, and vice versa. In addition, all replicas of a vertex must be **fully** connected to each other.

As an example:-

```
A === B
```

will become

```
A1 ----- B1
|        |
A2 ----- B2
```

Does this formulation match any well-defined graph theory problem? I am trying to come up with an algorithm that can make use of a GPU's speed, since the graphs I am dealing with can become huge, and I am trying to do it by manipulating the adjacency matrix.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question, but why would all-pair shortest path care about parallel edges? Can't you just remove the redundant ones?

Comment: I hardly understand what is your question. You first talk about "all-pair" shortest path for which basically you should have a look to Floyd-Warshall algorithm. Then you talk about a specific expansion of your graph. But what is your actual issue ?

Comment: I am sorry if my question was unclear. I know I can apply FW-algorithm to get all-pairs shortest paths. But that modification of the graph is necessary for the specific problem I am solving. However, I can not apply that expansion in an efficient way. I can not delete the parallel edges, since they are not redundant. Hence, my question.